# Subtracting row values in DAX ; Power BI

Tags: powerbi, m

If I have data of this sort:
[image]

I'd like to calculate the time difference between a value in Bi and Bi+1, in PowerBI. That is, in a new a column, in the Query Editor (so writing in M), I want to have:

C3 = B3-B2

C4 = B4 - B3

and so on.

Do you know how to achieve this in PowerBI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a calculated column like the below to compare each row against the previous then compute the difference in seconds using the `DATEDIFF` function:

```
Difference in Seconds =
DATEDIFF (
    'Table'[Time],
    CALCULATE (
        MIN ( [Time] ),
        FILTER ( ALL ( 'Table' ), [ID] < EARLIER ( 'Table'[ID] ) )
    ),
    SECOND
)
```

If you want to compare it against the previous ID time value, regardless if the time value is higher you can simply use:

```
Difference in Seconds =
DATEDIFF (
    'Table'[Time],
    CALCULATE (
        MIN ( [Time] ),
        FILTER ( ALL ( 'Table' ), [ID] = EARLIER ( 'Table'[ID] ) - 1 )
    ),
    SECOND
)
```

Using `LOOKUPVALUE`:

```
Difference in Seconds =
DATEDIFF (
    'Table'[Time],
    LOOKUPVALUE ( 'Table'[Time], 'Table'[ID], [ID] - 1 ),
    SECOND
)
```

**UPDATE:** Adding the column from source via M Language.

Use something like this in a custom column:

```
=Table.AddColumn(#"YourLastStep", "Diff",
 each
    (try DateTime.From(#"YourLastStep"[Time]{[ID]-2})
    otherwise DateTime.From([Time])) - [Time]  
 )
```

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: thank you for the comment;
I now realize I want this new column to be created in the Query Editor, so this calculation can be automated on refresh.
Do you know how to perform this in M?

Comment: @Mariah, In M it would be like the example I posted in my answer. Give it a try.